# How to use twig asset in a css file?

Tags: php, css, symfony, twig, include

So I want to import font using CSS.
I know how to work with `{{ asset('')}}` in twig/html pages ! but I don't know how to do that in a CSS file!

The current  css file code is :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'porta';
  src: url("../fonts/pluton.eot?49924914");
  src: url("../fonts/pluton.eot?49924914#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("../fonts/pluton.woff?49924914") format("woff"),
       url("../fonts/pluton.ttf?49924914") format("truetype"),
       url("../fonts/pluton.svg?49924914#porta") format('svg);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

What I did :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'porta';
  src: url("{{ asset('../fonts/pluton.eot?49924914') }}");
  src: url("{{ asset('../fonts/pluton.eot?49924914#iefix') }}") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("{{ asset('../fonts/pluton.woff?49924914') }}") format("woff"),
       url("{{ asset('../fonts/pluton.ttf?49924914') }}") format("truetype"),
       url("{{ asset('../fonts/pluton.svg?49924914#porta') }}") format("svg")
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I added asset like that but it didn't work ! So how to properly add CSS files?

Comment: css files usually are just delivered from the web server (nginx/apache) because that is exactly what happens for everything located in symfony's public folder. If you want to use twig in your css files, you would have to create a controller + route for that css files, see the css file as a twig template and so on. I don't think that this is actually a good idea. The question is: why would you want this? because I don't see a good reason ...

Comment: i  just download a template  from the internet and i am using it on my symfony project

Comment: the simple solution is: do not use twig functions (`asset` for example) in **static** files. when you put something in the `public` folder, they are usually static. you can only use twig functions in template files, and template files are used by controllers.

Answer (score -1):

asset() is a **twig** function, you can't use twig functions in css files. if you want to bundle your resources like images, fonts, css, js etc use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for example or if you are using php >= 7.1 use [webpack encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html)

Comment: i have no idea , how i am gonna do that , because i am not the one who did the front-end , i just download a template from the internet and i am working on the backend! i found a problem while implementing the fonts files !

Comment: Well I don't know who didnt the frontend but usually if the fonts / anything frontend related is in the web / public file and your css is in web/css / public/css the usual path is ../images or ../fonts ../webfonts ../anything